# How to do an upsert with MongoDB 2.0?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

The interface of MongoDB has completely changed from the previous one.
[Here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/reading_and_writing/) you can see the official documentation with some examples about how to search, insert and update but what about upserts?

Idea for meta:  I've tried to search on google and on SO but many resources refer to the old interface. Maybe it would be nice to create a MongoLegacy tag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Pass an instance of `UpdateOptions` as the options parameter in `UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, options)`, e.g.:

```
collection.UpdateOneAsync(p => p.Id == user.Id, 
    Builders<User>.Update.Set(p => p.Name, "John"), 
    new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

EDIT

To replace the document, call `ReplaceOneAsync` instead:

```
collection.ReplaceOneAsync(p => p.Id == user.Id, 
    user, 
    new ReplaceOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

Comment: works perfectly.. adding something like:   Builders<User>.Update.Set(p => p.Name, "John").Set(p => p.Age, 29) allows you to chain multiple field updates.

Comment: Suggested update: Use ReplaceOptions instead.

'IMongoCollection<Type>.ReplaceOneAsync(FilterDefinition<Type>, Type, UpdateOptions, CancellationToken)' is obsolete: 'Use the overload that takes a ReplaceOptions instead of an UpdateOptions.'