# MongoDB c# driver using upsert with updateMany

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

In MongoDB c# driver (2.0+) can we do an upsert when doing and updateManyAsync? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082599/how-to-do-an-upsert-with-mongodb-2-0) example helps with UpdateOne, but i am looking for something that works with updateMany.

Answer (score 5):

```
UpdateDefinition<Phone> updateDefinition = Builders<Phone>.Update.Set(x => x.Name, "Updated Name");
MongoDb.GetCollection<Phone>("Phone").UpdateOne(x => x._id == "foo", updateDefinition); // replaces first match
MongoDb.GetCollection<Phone>("Phone").UpdateMany(x => x.SomeProp == 5, updateDefinition); // replaces all matches
```

Assuming you have a class:

```
class Phone
{
    public string _id {get; set;} // this is the primary key because Mongo uses _id as primary key
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int SomeProp {get;set;}

    // etc...
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more complete example of using UpdateMany in C# .Net core:

```
BostadsUppgifterMongoDbContext context = new BostadsUppgifterMongoDbContext(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), _configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnectionName"]);
var residenceCollection = context.MongoDatabase.GetCollection<Residence>("Residences");
residenceCollection.UpdateMany(x =>
    x.City == "Stockholm",
    Builders<Residence>.Update.Set(p => p.Municipality, "Stoholms län"),
    new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = false }
);
```

If `IsUpsert` is set to true it will insert a document if no match was found.

Answer (score 1):

Upsert works fine when using [updateMany](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.1/reference/driver/crud/writing/#upserts) aswell:

```
var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };
var result = await collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update, options);
```

Comment: could you please explain filter and update. 
And by explain i mean words + example 
lets say i have a model person and i would like to upsert many people.
they are are unique by id. GO

Answer (score -2):

TModel is your model

```
var updateBuilder = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<TModel>();
yourContext.UpdateMany(filterExpression, update.Set(updateExpression, updateValue));
```

Comment: What are filterExpression, updateValue and yourContext? updateBuilder isn't even used in your example also